# Remove <xyz> but gain data between

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Problem:
xyz.xml

```xml
<password>neverend/password>
```

So, basically, I read by a simple method

```
public string xml_test_read()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xyz.xml");
    var return_pw = doc.Element("password");
    return return_pw.ToString();
}
```

The return is:

```xml
<password>neverend/password>
```

I only want to get "neverend", but dunno how... I tried two possible ways, I got

```xml
</ password>
```

as result. How to fix it, it would help me a LOT!

Comment: You are missing `<` on the beginning of your end tags, is this a typo or intentional?

Comment: Use [`XElement.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`XElement.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets the concatenated text contents of this element.

I.e.

```
return (return_pw == null ? null : return_pw.Value);
```